# Work Email not working on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, email, thunderbird, ms-exchange

I have tried all sort of things to get my email working on my ubuntu, maybe you guys can help. Let me first say that my work uses MS exchange server. They have changed the server names not to be the expected server names for security purposes. This is what I have figured out so far.

When I use the Windows 10 eMail program it works.
When I use my Andoid phone's eMail app it works.
When I use my Mac's email program it does not work.
When I use Thunderbird, it does not work.

It seems like mobile email applications work. Weird. The reson why I am saying this is, my Mac OS does not allow me to connect, Ubuntu does not allow me to connect, ex cept windows 10 (touch) email and android.

I then tried Thunderbird's MS exchange extension called OWA. When adding an email account via Firebird, it directs to a company login page and then it opens the webmail. It does not allow me to just authenticate. When I close that window, it complains about the window being closed and that it could not authenticate.

Can anyone tell me how do I get the option to manually try and enter the information. Even when I try to use the manual configuration, it only gives my POP3 and IMAP options.

So I don't know anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to do this for several years but I used to use davmail (http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) along with evolution and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go

Comment: Still does not work. I get the feeling it might be that some email clients are approved by my company by means of security keys.